# How do I capitalize an entire text except for certain patterns?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text (string) that I want in all upper case, except the following:

1. Words starting with :  (colon)
2. Words or strings surrounded by double quotation marks, ""
3. Words or strings surrounded by single quotation marks, ''

Everything else should be replaced with its upper case counterpart, and formatting (whitespaces, line breaks, etc.) should remain.

How would I go about doing this using Regex (C# style/syntax)?

Comment: what if the text is """like that?""" (three quotation marks)

Comment: @Shai: I tried doing it fully programatically, which turned out to quickly become very iffy with the formatting part.Only one additional

Comment: @elyashiv: That should never happen. There'll only be one set of quotation marks per string.

Comment: What is a 'word' exactly? Can quote marks occur unpaired or within other pairs of quote marks?

Comment: @reinierpost Think of a regular string (in most common programming languages). As in, there'll ALWAYS be sets of quotation marks, and always only one. If there are quotation marks within the string, they'll be escaped (but this should never theoretically happen)

Comment: @Noollab: This is not yet specific enough to write a solution. Which characters may occur in a word? How are words separated? How much checking for unpaired or escaped quote marks is good enough (it really complicates the regexps)?

Comment: @reinierpost - Usually, you are correct that a definition of "word" is required, and difficult. Here, we can probably live with "anything that can be converted to upper case" - so really, we only need letters. (though, there are still words like `"don't"`, which will mess with the quotes)

Comment: @Kobi: So words can include `:`, newlines, and null characters?

Comment: @reinierpost - Does your culture have upper-case versions for `:`, `\n`, and `\0`? If so then yes, they should be included. My culture, for example, as no upper case letters at all, so the task here is very simple `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, character sets are another issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @":\w+|""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|(.)",
                     match => match.Groups[1].Success ?
                              match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() : match.Value);
```

- `:\w+` - match words with a colon.
- `"[^"]*"|'[^']*'` - match quoted text. For escaped quotes, you may use:

  ```
  "[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
  ```
- `(.)` - capture anything else (you can also try `([^"':]*|.)`, it might be faster).

Next, we use a callback for [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) to do two things:

- Determine if we need to keep the text as-is, or
- Return the upper-case version of the text.

Working example: http://ideone.com/ORFU8

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this RegEx:

```
\b(?<![:"'])(\w+?)(?!["'])\b
```

But of course you have to improve it by yourself, if it is not enough.
For example this will also not find "dfgdfg' (not equal quotation)
The word which is found is in the first match ($1)